# Explanation of Conditions of Equivalent Electric Circuits

Tags: circuit-analysis

Two electric linear circuits are equivalent when they have the same voltage-current relation at the terminals of interest under all circumstances.

In order to check if two circuits are equivalent across two terminals you have to

1. Turn off the current sources and find the equivalent open-circuit resistance across the terminals in both circuits
2. Short-circuit the terminals and find the short-circuit current flowing there

What I can't find is why those two procedures ensure that the circuits are equivalent under all circumstances?

Why we only check for open-circuit resistance and shot-circuit current?

If you could link material or sites or books (even better) explaining the reason I would be glad.

Comment: You might find [this answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/110501/9887) helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only true for linear circuits.  If you graph the current versus voltage in the VI plane you get a line.  For the open circuit, you get a point on the V axis.  For the short you get a point on the I axis.  Since all circuits that draw a line through the same points are the same line, they are equivalent.

Comment: Indeed I forgot the linear part. I edited my question to include it because it was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Not only does it only apply to linear devices but also non-reactive loads that are frequency selective.    However with certain assumptions on standard characteristics, one can determine the the transient response is the same.

## If the VI load line is linear and matched then the end-points Voc and Isc are the same.

## Why non-linear nodes don't apply?

One supply might have a constant current limiter while the other a resistor in series giving the same Isc. So this does not apply as the CC Regulator is "non-linear".

## Exceptions

For Photo Voltaics for example. If two units are the same array size and receive the same solar input. They should have the same open circuit Voltage Voc and Isc.  Although non-linear they have the same non-linearity.  A small array might have the same voltage but a much smaller current. and a shunt array would have a greater current but lower voltage at the same size.